# line drawable below textview not showing

Tags: android, xml-drawable

I have a textview i want to show a line below it. I am using the drawableBottom attribute to do this. Here is my code

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/total"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="right"
 android:text="TextView" 
 android:drawableBottom="@drawable/dividerline"/>
```

here is my dividerline.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="line">

    <stroke
        android:width="70dp"
        android:color="@android:color/black"
        />
    <size
        android:height="1dp"
     />
    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/black"
    />

</shape>
```

I am not getting errors. Its just that when I run my app no line appears below the textview.

Have a misunderstood drawableBottom attribute? Looking forward to some help:)

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020466/android-4-0-sub-title-section-label-styling) post for same issue

Comment: @arjukhan see the solution I have posted.

Comment: thanks ρяσѕρєя K works gr8

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <size
        android:height="1dp"
        android:width="70dp" />

    <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />

</shape>
```

Comment: It is only taking some space of the screen. How can we make the shape to take entire space. i.e, "fill_parent"?

Answer (score -3):

Use Linkify

```
phone_no.setText("1222446");
Linkify.addLinks(phone_no, Linkify.ALL);
```

It will show automatically line below textview

Comment: Questionnaire asked about having line bottom of the text but not to Linkify text

Comment: Add <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dip" ></View> and give specific color

Comment: ya i'd rather not use a link. will try out the other option

Comment: The most sarcastic solution.