# Section Header using Android XML?

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface

`enter code here`Looking through the Android UI guidelines I came across this section / example:

[image]

In the example above, there are a few headers called 'SECTION' with a horizontal line underneath them.

Im still getting grips with the appropriate way to replicate this - 
Is there something specific like a `Header` XML element to use that will automatically style the font and horizontal line? Or is something like this generally more primitive, i.e. A `TextView` with a 1 pixel horizontal image (`ImageView`?) underneath it?

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate question of this one: [Android 4.0 Sub-Title (section) Label Styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020466/android-4-0-sub-title-section-label-styling)

In short: try adding attribute `style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"` to the TextView element, which you wish to make look like that, in the XML layout file.