# How to make a TextView look like a Setting's PreferenceCategory Header

Tags: android, textview, android-preferences

This should be something pretty easy to figure out, but I've just not been able to find the answer anywhere.

I am trying to make a regular TextView look very similar, to the Preference Category Headers presented on Settings for any app. Here's what I mean:

[image: Preference Category Header]

Now, I have tried a few things, but I seem not to get it right. For example, I tried setting this:

```
android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
```

to my TextView, but that seems not to do anything at all, and my TextView Still looks like this:

[image: Image not looking correctly]

I've also tried simply setting a drawable I made:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"         
    android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"
    />
</shape>
```

But That didn't come up on my text either.

This is the TextView style for now:

```
 <style name="NewTaskHeaderText">
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:padding">8dp</item>
</style>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    style="@style/NewTaskHeaderText"
    android:drawableBottom="@android:attr/dividerVertical"
    android:text="@string/some_text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="foo"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle" />
```

To do even more, look at this [other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020466/android-4-0-sub-title-section-label-styling)

Comment: Note that this "attr" style actually uses a ninepatch drawable background to display the under line. 
Original Android style is like :

<style name="Widget.Holo.Light.TextView.ListSeparator" parent="Widget.TextView.ListSeparator">
<item name="android:background">@android:drawable/list_section_divider_holo_light</item><item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 2):

Try using a simple `View` after the `TextView`:

```
<View 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
</View
```