# System subheadings in Android app

Tags: android, user-interface, heading

Like here.

[image]

Like those blue `phone`, `email` , `adress`. I've been googling for a while, havn't found any built-in way to add them :(. Is there any? (Supporting 2.3, preferably)

**Here is the same question with good answer too**: [Android 4.0 Sub-Title (section) Label Styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020466/android-4-0-sub-title-section-label-styling)

**And here is the *more or less* good way to reach what I want (but it's grey):** `<TextView style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle" ... >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get 2.x support, you can use the [HoloEverywhere library](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere).

The style you are looking for is "Holo.TextView.ListSeparator(.Light)"